# SQL Server Agent unable to run SQLCMD

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlcmd

An SQL Server instance was set up without access to the Internet and failed to install SQLCMD during the initial SQL Server installation process. Upon discovering this SQLCMD was installed through the MsSqlCmdLnUtils.msi installer. Can now run SQLCMD through command line, as user account, but when running SQLCMD as part of `xp_cmdshell` the error is

> 'sqlcmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.

I've manually given read/write access to all the SQLCmd files, i.e. .exe, .rll, etc, to the SQL Agent NT account. I can manually run the sqlcmd through command line as user account. Xp_cmdshell can run successfully when given other command line tasks, i.e. moving files, mapping drives, etc. Restarted SQL Server Agent.

```sql
SET @sqlCommand =
    'sqlcmd -S hqconnectsql1 -d M -Q "SET NOCOUNT ON; select * from temp_travelSurvey" -o"' +
    @filePath + @fileName +
    '" -W -s"|" -w 1024'

EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @sqlCommand
GO
```

The above code is what is failing when run as a query through SSMS, left out are the variables that are declared and set prior to the command.

```sql
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'net use Y: \\HQPCISQL\e$ troperM12 /USER:aaa177\Reportsrv'
go
```

This code works successfully when run as a query through SSMS, showing that `xp_cmdshell` is not the issue.

The expected result, which I have been able to have succeed when run through the command prompt, is for a file containing the content of `temp_travelSurvey` to be created. Current error message is the sqlcmd is not a recognized internal or external command.

Comment: Can you simply run the SQL Server installer again? It will let you chose additional elements to install.

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/803367/52365

Comment: The SQLCMD.exe is kept in a folder on the D drive, where the SQL Server engine is installled, and that location is listed under the Path system variable. Which makes sense since you can run SQLCMD from command prompt as intended.

Comment: @IThompson Have you restarted the SQL Server service since you manually installed sqlcmd.exe and updated the System environment variables with a custom `PATH` value? Windows processes, including SQL Server, only get a copy of environment variables when they start up. They won't see any changes to System or User environment variables until they next restart. You can check which environment variables SQL Server can currently see by running this on the server: `exec xp_cmdshell 'SET'`.

Answer (score 0):

on SSMS you can execute your sql directly, you need not to use SQLCMD there. SQLCMD is command line interface to execute SQL from command prompt. I hope this would help you.

Like in above case directly execute sql scripts as below.

select * from temp_travelSurvey